# sed/awk : match a pattern and return everything between the end of the pattern and a semicolon

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

I have a line:

`<random junk>TYPE=snp;<more random junk>`

and I need to return everything between the end of `TYPE=` and the `;` (in this case `snp` but it could be any of a number of text strings.

I tried various sed / awk solutions but I can't seem to get it working. I have the feeling this is a simple problem so, sorry about that.

Comment: I assume `<random junk>` can't include `TYPE=` and `<more random junk>` can't include `;`. Is that correct?

Comment: `<random junk>` and `<more random junk>` will both include more `;`, but there is only one instance of `TYPE=` in the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
sed 's/.*TYPE=\(.*\);.*/\1/'
```

**EDIT:**

Ah, so there can be semicolons in the random junk. Try this:

```
sed 's/.*TYPE=\([^;]*\);.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Partially, it returns: `snp;XAI=0.0037843;XAM=0.0170293;XAS=0.013245;XRI=0;XRM=0;XRS=0` , but all I want is `snp`, i.e. it returns the random junk after the semicolon, and the semicolon, which I don't want.

Comment: Using `-r` will make it look cleaner since you don't need to escape the brackets, see steve’s answer.

Comment: @exic: true, but that would make it make it specific to GNU sed. (I'll bet the OP is using GNU sed, but it would still make the answer less generally useful.)

Comment: @Beta - actually BSD sed also supports ERE using the `-E` option.  This covers FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD and OS X.  Recent versions of FreeBSD (I'm not sure about the others) also add `-r` for compatibility with GNU sed.  Of course, this doesn't help with older unices, SVR4, Solaris, etc.  Anyway, I agree with using BRE in sed where the target platform is unknown, so +1 from me. :)

Comment: Doesn't work! Even a simple `echo Hello | sed 's/\(*\)o/\1/'` shows up the whole word instead of a pattern.

Comment: @YagamyLight: Did you post that comment by mistake? It does not pertain to my Answer. If you have difficulty with `sed`, I will try to help; what was the intent of your `sed` statement?

Comment: @Beta why doesn't pertain? I am trying to take a pattern from a text via your code, slightly modified though. But I am already found where I was wrong: in the text above the dot was needed before the `*` character. Have no idea why -- from what I know, it should have been worked without a dot, looks like a bug. Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 4):

requires GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=TYPE=)[^;]+'
```

meaning: preceded by "TYPE=", find some non-semicolon characters

Comment: This get's my vote. There's nothing like a good lookbehind assertion.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.*TYPE=([^;]+).*/\1/' file.txt
```

Comment: You should see a tick to the left of my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you also tagged this **awk**:

```
$ text='<random junk>TYPE=snp;<more random junk>'
$ echo "$text" | awk -FTYPE= '{sub(/;.*/,"",$2); print $2}'
snp
$ text='foo=bar;baz=fnu;TYPE=snp;XAI=0;XAM=0'
$ echo "$text" | awk -FTYPE= '{sub(/;.*/,"",$2); print $2}'
snp
```

(Only using the variable to keep the lines from wrapping.)

Or, to parse this as set of `variable=value` pairs rather than just a string of text:

```
$ echo "$text" | awk -vRS=";" -F= '$1=="TYPE" {print $2}'
snp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in pure bash, if you want:

```
$ t="red=blue;TYPE=snp;XAI=0.0037843;XAM=0.0170293;XAS=0.013245;XRI=0;XRM=0"
$ t=${t#*TYPE=}
$ t=${t%%;*}
$ echo $t
snp
```